# For Bootstrap 4 site should I add container-fluid at body or main level

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For Bootstrap 4 site should I add container-fluid at body or main level

i.e

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body class= "container-fluid">
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>
<main class= "container-fluid"></main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

What would be more usual ?

In the second, would it be usual to have a container for each section, 
i.e.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header class= "container-fluid"></header>
<main class= "container-fluid"></main>
<footer class= "container-fluid"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not advised to use at body level, because if you have background color, then margin spacing will be visible as white border created by container-fluid.  Give it to header, main, footer as applicable to your website look and feel. (note: head section is not for display, so no use of giving class to it.)

Comment: best advise is to go check source of free templates. Open any bootstrap 4 template website and right click and `view source`.

Comment: Thankyou do you think usually should be just main because header and footer shoud be full width without margin or not ?

Comment: i haven't used it for header and footer, because i don't want any margin for them. but still i used inside header and footer for there child div's (so content will margin and you will still have full background color).

Comment: sample page https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html, check its source code (view-source:https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** In my opinion container is something, what is sub-body part and can be multiple times on page. And btw I don't see benefit from using header, main and footer blocks. But at your case I would do this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Ad.: Some css frameworks has some styles for elements header, main, footer. In that case, you should inspect these elements.

**Second:** I don't think that's good idea. At least **< head >** cannot have styles. Other element like **header, main and footer** usually work same as div, so you can add class to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_get_started.php) has a very clear definition on this:

> *Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap **site contents.***

and it says **site**, an entire web site, because these classes (`container` or `container-fluid`) provide facilities to contain and adjust an entire web site document and you put an entire website in this element, whenever you use Bootstrap CSS Framework.

There are two container classes to choose from:

1. The `.container` class provides a responsive fixed width container
2. The `.container-fluid` class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport